# Joining area that has been split into many .dwg or .gml files

Tags: software-recommendations, gml, dwg, free-software, online-viewer

How do I merge multiple adjacent (1) dwg or (2) gml files into a continuous map using free software or online?

Comment: QGIS? will merge them into one file

Comment: @Mapperz treasure trove, thank you

Comment: @Mapperz ok downloaded, manual tl/dr - how do i import the files?

Comment: drag and drop into the map window in QGIS and merge > https://youtu.be/K7taKodrjcM?t=94